# Filter the json data by grouping the data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object with key `cgi, tag and name` key where cgi is repeated in any multiple object if any cgi get the tag as 'revert' then that cgi should not get returned.

```
[
  {
    "cgi": "abc-123",
    "tag": "revert",
    "name": "Piyush"
  },
  {
    "cgi": "abc-123",
    "tag": null,
    "name": "Piyush"
  },
  {
    "cgi": "abc-456",
    "tag": null,
    "name": "Piyush"
  },
  {
    "cgi": "abc-789",
    "tag": null,
    "name": "Piyush"
  }
]
```

Then the output will be

```
[
  {
    "cgi": "abc-456",
    "tag": null,
    "name": "Piyush"
  },
  {
    "cgi": "abc-789",
    "tag": null,
    "name": "Piyush"
  }
]
```

Attempt:

```
data = data.filter(es => es.tag == 'filter')
```

`abc-123` got rejected as in first index tag is 'revert'. I have tried using filter but it doest gave me appropriate answer.

Comment: one option would be to create a map of set which has revert. then using that filter the array `const rev = new Set(a.filter(b => b.tag === 'revert').map(b => b.cgi));
const res = a.filter(b => !rev.has(b.cgi));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a collection of all reverted `cgi` values. Afterwards you can use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out all unwanted values based in this collection.

*Instead of [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) you could also simply use an array. I've used a Set so we don't get duplicate values.

```js
const data = [{"cgi":"abc-123","tag":"revert","name":"Piyush"},{"cgi":"abc-123","tag":null,"name":"Piyush"},{"cgi":"abc-456","tag":null,"name":"Piyush"},{"cgi":"abc-789","tag":null,"name":"Piyush"}];

// Get all `cgi` where tag is `revert`.
const revertedTags = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if(item.tag === 'revert') {
    acc.add(item.cgi);
  }

  return acc;
}, new Set());

// Filter out all elements who are present in `revertedTags` collection.
const filteredTags = data.filter((item) => !revertedTags.has(item.cgi));

// Result.
console.log(filteredTags);
```

Answer (score 0):

An one-liner: you can use a memoized function as a filter to filter the items:

```js
const data = [{"cgi":"abc-123","tag":"revert","name":"Piyush"},{"cgi":"abc-123","tag":null,"name":"Piyush"},{"cgi":"abc-456","tag":null,"name":"Piyush"},{"cgi":"abc-789","tag":null,"name":"Piyush"}];

const filteredTags = data.filter((map => e => map[e.cgi] ??= !data.find(e2 => e2.tag === 'revert' && e.cgi === e2.cgi))({}));

console.log(filteredTags);
```